# Проверка вводимых значений

Tags: массивы, java, исключения, scanner

```
public int[] move() {
    System.out.println("Введите два числа:");
    try {
        xy[0] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        xy[1] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println("Введено не число");
        move();
    }
    return xy;
}
```

Когда вводится число и строка, то корректное значение сохраняется в массиве. 
   Почему оно не перезаписывается?
   Пример вывода:

```
/*
Введите два числа:
t 0
Введено не число
Введите два числа:
1 1
Output: 0 1
[ ][ ][ ]
[X][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ]
*/
```

**update:**

```
public int[] getXY(){
    while (true){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
          if (scanner.hasNext()){
              xy[0] = scanner.nextInt();
              xy[1] = scanner.nextInt();
          }
        break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex){
            System.out.println("Input error, try again.");
        }
    }
    return xy;
```

}

Код переписал, теперь все работает. xy объявлен в классе.
Как я понял буфер сканера очистить никак нельзя?

Comment: Ээээ, ну и код у вас, о боже. А откуда берётся `xy` внутри процедуры?

Comment: похоже на то что, у тебя неправильные пары, ошибка была уже после t, следующая пара (0,1), а не (1,1)

Comment: вместо того чтоб использовать рекурсию лучше сделайте вечный цикл с условием выхода, т.к. у вас может быть `stack overflow exception`, кроме того вместо `sc.next` лучше использовать `nextInt` и ему подобные методы

Comment: эм...у Вас сканер один и тот же.. в общем он фэйлится на на букве t, но впереди то ноль, Вы его снова дергаете, у Вас читается 0 и следующая 1, еще одна 1 осталась в сканере.....блин никогда так не делайте...

Comment: А почему бы не завести внутри `getXY` новый локальный `xy`? А то если вы два раза вызовете эту процедуру, старые данные затрутся.

Comment: @VladD, не поможет же. Хотя.. Это ж не по вопросу комментарий, а в принципе? Тогда согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, просто комментарий к коду из вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Вся проблема в том, что в случае использовании такого кода:

```
public int[] move() {
    System.out.println("Введите два числа:");
    try {
        xy[0] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        xy[1] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println("Введено не число");
        move();
    }
    return xy;
}
```

когда мы вводим `t 0` происходит генерация исключения в строке, где мы пытаемся прочитать значение для `xy[0]`, соответственно остаётся ещё ноль в строке, который будет прочитан при следующем обращении к сканеру. Можно использовать метод `reset`, чтобы очистить сканер от оставшегося ненужного значения:

```
public int[] move() {
    System.out.println("Введите два числа:");
    try {
        xy[0] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        xy[1] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println("Введено не число");
        sc.reset();
        move();
    }
    return xy;
}
```